# Hide previously opened child views when linking to parent with ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have a map with markers on it. When you click a marker a child view opens with the marker details.

```
.state('map', {
    url: '/map',
    ...
})
.state('map.detail', {
    url: '/:markerId',
    ...
})
```

If you open a marker's details, navigate away from the map, then back to the map using `ui-sref="map"` the url will change to `/map/<markerId>` with the child view open.

I'd like to go straight to `/map` when clicking on `ui-sref="map"` but **don't want to reload the `'map'`** just hide any child view.

Is there a simple way to do this? I've tried combinations of `cache: false` on the two states but that doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully sure, what is your issue. Because this

> ...I'd like to go straight to /map when clicking on ui-sref="map" but don't want to reload the map just hide any child view...

is the default behavior of UI-Router. There is **[a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ktOTFyp6aZBTrfLvi8uQ?p=info)**

These links, will not trigger RE-init of parent controller *(`'map'` state)*

```
<a ui-sref="map">
<a ui-sref="map.detail({markerId:1})">
<a ui-sref="map.detail({markerId:22})">
```

And states like this:

```
  .state('map', {
      url: "/map",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'ParentCtrl',
  })
  .state('map.detail', { 
      url: "/:markerId",
      templateUrl: 'child.html',
      controller: 'ChildCtrl',
  })
```

And both controllers:

```
.controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
  $scope.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
}])
.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
  $scope.timestamp = new Date().getTime();
}])
```

And we can see, that `'map'` state is still not changed

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ktOTFyp6aZBTrfLvi8uQ?p=info)

Comment: There must be something wrong with my `ui-router` setup then because the child view is not going away when the state changes to `map`. I'm also using `ionic-framework` so maybe that has something to do with it.